# Swift: URLRequest uses body as JSON key

Tags: swift

I'm using a generic function for POST requests in my app. I have the following function:

```
func PostRequest<In:Codable>(object: In, endpoint: String){
    do{
                
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/\(endpoint)/")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
                
        request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else{
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No Data")
                return
            }
            let JSONResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let JSONResponse = JSONResponse as? [String: Any] {
                print(JSONResponse)
            }
        }.resume()
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And in this case, the `object` is the following struct:

```
struct MarkAsDelivered: Codable{
    let whoCollected: String
    let deliveryID: Int
}
```

When I print the result of JSONEncoder().encode(object) as a string, it returns the following, as would be expected:

```
{
    "whoCollected":"TESTNAME",
    "deliveryID":140
}
```

however, when i view this JSON object on my backend, it returns it as the following:

```
{
    "{\"whoCollected\":\"TESTNAME\",\"deliveryID\":140}" : ""
}
```

From what I can tell, it is using the JSON object as a key.
Does anyone know what has caused this issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you receive any error code? You are probably missing the content type.

Comment: @burnsi Adding a content type fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as @burnsi mentioned in the comments to my question, I was indeed missing the content type. Specifying it fixed my issue:

```
func PostRequest<In:Codable>(object: In, endpoint: String){
    do{
                
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/\(endpoint)/")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //Added content type on line below:
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else{
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No Data")
                return
            }
            let JSONResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let JSONResponse = JSONResponse as? [String: Any] {
                print(JSONResponse)
            }
        }.resume()
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```